# error using $this on create_function

Tags: php, create-function

When I'm using `$this` inside `create_function` I'm getting an error

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

```
create_function('$model, $this', 'return $this->di->getStatus($model->getStatus)');
```

Later on I call it like

```
$function($model, $this);
```

I passed `$this` to the function, but doesn't seems to work. There is a way to get around it?

Thanks

Comment: I think people assumed  (as you havn't shown otherwise) that you're not aware $this` can only be used in a class context. Perhaps show in your question that the function does indeed reside within a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging and research I found out that my code was being wrapped in a function, so the end result was something like

```
function($var1, $var2) { return create_function()}
```

This way a closure was created and `$this` was no longer in the scope that I wanted.

More about closures here:
http://php.net/manual/ro/class.closure.php